# Sending POST request in WinForms app and displaying result in browser

Tags: .net, post, browser, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I have to interact with a 3rd party web service. I call a method in the service using `POST` and it returns a web page. This works fine, but the problem I have is that the web request is called from a windows forms application and the 3rd party expects the response to be shown in a browser. It sounds like it should be possible but I can't think of a way of passing the response to the browser.

Comment: Can you display it in a `WebBrowser` control in your application? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2te2y1x6.aspx

Comment: We have a `WebBrowser` control, but how do you pass a POST request from the application via the `WebBrowser`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, very silly of me. Using the `WebBrowser` control was indeed the answer. But it had extra parameters, in the `Navigate` method, that allowed you to pass in post data. Don't know how I overlooked this. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The WebBrowser control is your best bet here.

The control exposes a DocumentStream property that lets you load content from a stream:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentstream.aspx

You could also use the DocumentText property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documenttext.aspx